# Simple if statement

Tags: c#

What does the `if` statement mean here?

```
Merchant merchant1 =new Merchant();

if(!merchant1.SaveMerchantDdetails(x, y, z))
{
    lblError.txt = "some error info"; 
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Is it really that hard to understand what if does here?

Comment: @ Akash : Remember the days you started learning Asp.Net! The very first day!!! you will know why i asked. 
Guys: I WAS NOT KIDDING. I thought if statement is only to compare objects like int, etc and not this part where it checks. If it is really an easy question, sorry!

Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means that if the `SaveMerchantDdetails` method called on the `merchant1` instance returns `false` it will set an error value to an error label.

Comment: Top answer, ignoring everything else, that really is just what the "IF" does.

Answer (score 4):

When the save action for **`MerchantDdetails`** failes the method returns `false` in this case an error is shown by setting the error text.

Answer (score 4):

If you write the code like this, it is much clearer what is happening. To have a local variable is also better for debugging.

```
    Merchant merchant1 =new Merchant(); 
    bool sucess = merchant1.SaveMerchantDdetails(x, y, z);
    if(sucess == false) 
    {
      lblError.txt = "some error info"; 
    }
```

So your code executes the method `SaveMerchantDdetails` on a object of the type `Merchant`. If it fails, a label (lbl would hint to that...) text is set to "some error info".

Comment: this is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: It's perfectly clear what is happening in the original code.  The boolean variable just clutters things up.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure what exactly `SaveMerchantDetails()` methods does but it might mean if merchant doesn't save x.y,z then do the following in braces...

Answer (score 0):

if result of SaveMerchantDdetails not true then 
 lblError.txt = "some error info";

Answer (score 0):

If the call to the `SaveMerchantDetails` method returns `false` -- presumably because the details couldn't be saved properly for some reason -- then set the `txt` property of `lblError` to *"some error info"*; otherwise execute whatever code is in the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

The method `SaveMerchantDetails` gets called with the arguments `x`, `y` and `z`. It does what ever it does and returns a boolean to indicate success or failure.

By testing `!merchant1.SaveMerchantDetails(x, y, z)` the code is testing for the `false` or error state.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is being used to determine whether the Boolean return value of the method `merchant1.SaveMerchantDdetails();` is true or false.

In this case if the method returns false then a label's text property is updated with the string shown. If the method returns true then the else block will be run instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to this. This simple IF statement is saying that if Merchant1 from `SaveMerchantDdetails` is false, then output an error message (apparently generated by another function)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Merchant class there will be a method something like

```
public bool SaveMerchantDdetails(var x, var y, var z)
{
  bool isSaved = false;

  // Save Merchant Details and check if the save worked, store whether it did in isSave

  return isSaved;
}
```

So the code:

```
if(!merchant1.SaveMerchantDdetails(x, y, z))
```

is simply checking if the boolean return from the SaveMerchantDdetails method is true or false.  If the return is false then the error is displayed.